# How to add dynamic validators to an angular reactive form control

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I was using angular's reactive forms. The use-case is that the form is being created dynamically with the field's value and types coming from BE. Also the validators for the fields are coming from BE too.
I am able to create the form dynamically but adding validators dynamically is giving me error.

```
control.addValidators(Validators[validator]()
```

where validator is a dynamic string which could be 'pattern', 'required', 'minLength' etc.

The error I am getting for this are

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof Validators'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof Validators'.
```

Comment: I don't know Typescript very well, but the error you shared reads like a type error (from Typescript) more than something with Angular itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect scenario to use `any`

With any

```
const test: string = 'maxLength';
    const validator: any = Validators[<keyof Validators>test];
    const nonFunctionValidators: Array<string> = ['required'];
    if (validator) {
      control.addValidators(
        nonFunctionValidators.includes(test) ? validator : validator(10)
      );
    }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jm8fr3?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

---

But I guess it does not help you so you are here, here is my solution, which does not cause any typescript errors, but you need to define the `non function validators` explicitly!

```
const test: string = 'maxLength';
const validator: ValidatorFn | ((...args: number[]) => ValidatorFn) =
  Validators[<keyof Validators>test];
const nonFunctionValidators: Array<string> = ['required'];
if (validator) {
  control.addValidators(
    nonFunctionValidators.includes(test)
      ? validator 
      : (validator as (...args: number[]) => ValidatorFn)(10)
  );
}
```

[stackblitz not giving error for this code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jm8fr3?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Thanks, but if I've to pass arguments to the validator function like, Validators.minLength(10), if I add the calling parentheses to the method above, it gives me error: This expression is not callable. Type 'never' has no call signatures.